# Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, nav

Before I start this question, if anybody do not want to give me an answer please do not assign this post as solved, because no one of this solution helps me in this case.

This is my code:

```js
// Collapse Navbar
var navbarCollapse = function() {
  if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
    $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
  } else {
    $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you add your css or include library of bootstrap or jquery you are using

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem by separating the declaration and the method calling:

```
var navbarCollapse = function() {
  var mainNav = $("#mainNav");
  if (mainNav.offset().top > 100) {
    mainNav.addClass("navbar-shrink");
  } else {
    mainNav.removeClass("navbar-shrink");
  }
};
```